# Tool simulating RAM usage

Tags: windows, ram

Is there a tool which can consume a certain amount of memory in Windows 7 (64 bit)?

I want to test the behaviour of software when the available RAM gets low.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a tool called TestLimit from Sysinternals by the well-known Mark Russinovich. You can get it from: [Microsoft Sysinternals - Testlimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/testlimit) as 32 and 64 bit versions. [DL-Link](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/Testlimit.zip)

To allocate 1024 MB you can do the following:

```
testlimit64.exe -d 1024 -c 1
```

And end it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

The following command line options are available:

> ```
> C:\Users\\...>testlimit64.exe
> ```

```
Testlimit v5.04 - test Windows limits
By Mark Russinovich - www.sysinternals.com
```

> 

```
usage: testlimit [[-h [-u]] | [-p [-n]] | [-t [-n [KB]]] | [-u [-i]] | [-g [object size]] | [-a|-d|-l|-m|-r|-s [MB]] | [-w]] [-c [count]]
  -a       Leak Address Windowing Extensions (AWE) memory in
           specified MBs (default is 1).
  -c       Count of number of objects to allocate (default is as many as
           possible). This must be the last option specified.
  -d       Leak and touch memory in specified MBs (default is 1).
  -g       Create GDI handles of specified size (default 1 byte).
           Specify a size of 0 to cause GDI object exhaustion.
  -h       Create handles. Specify -u to also allocate file objects.
  -i       Exhaust USER desktop heap.
  -l       VirtualLock memory in specified MBs (default is 1).
  -m       Leak memory in specified MBs (default is 1).
  -p       Create processes - add -n to set min working set. Add -n to
           set min working set of processes to smallest.
  -r       Reserve memory in specified MBs (default is 1).
  -s       Leak shared memory in specified MBs (default is 1).
  -t       Create threads - add -n to specify minimum stack reserve (in KB).
  -u       Create USER handles to menus.
  -w       Reset working set minimum to highest possible value.
```